# Is it possible for an end-user to change the annex-type of a DSL modem/router?

Tags: networking, router, adsl, dsl-modem

Does someone have experience in changing the annex of a DSL modem/router?

I found some reports from UK but no complete instructions or success stories?

I bought a [TP-Link Archer D7](http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/cat-15_Archer-D7.html) (Annex A) and four weeks later the annex type for the region was changed from A to B/J. Of course the return period for the router is over and I would like to keep it.

Any hints welcome. And for the record, if “let me Google that for you” would answer my question, I wouldn’t be posting here.

Answer (score 4):

#### I wonder if it is maybe impossible?

- Annex A is ADSL over POTS
- Annex B is ADSL over ISDN
- Annex J is ADSL2

It **may** be possible if you can find a revised firmware for your modem.

---

#### DSL: Annex A versus B

> It's a different DSL protocol defining how the internet circuit is
>   combined with the phone circuit on a telephone line. Modems for Annex
>   A can't be used on Annex B lines and vice versa. Annex B was designed
>   to work in collaboration with ISDN telephone lines (and can be used on
>   normal POTS lines) which is why it became the standard in Germany. UK
>   has/had very little ISDN services, so they adopted Annex A.
>
> Traditionally the protocol was hard-coded into the modem firmware, so
>   could not be changed, but more modern modems can sometimes be
>   re-flashed or re-programmed, (sometimes with hacks) with different
>   firmware so can be changed. Manufacturers don't encourage or support
>   changing the protocol because of support issues.

Source [DSL: Annex A versus B](http://www.toytowngermany.com/forum/topic/308136-dsl-annex-a-versus-b/)

Comment: I am 99% sure that there are devices out there which can handle both with the same hardware (there are reports out there that this is the case for at least some devices from AVM), and there are devices out there which come in hardware variants (I know of at least one case). I'd contact the vendor in this regard. If at all possible, that may be the start of a rough ride, because I wouldn't bet on the firmware being identical and/or the firmware being configurable in an obvious way in this regard and/or the firmware being exchangeable in a clean way.

Comment: @ClassStacker OP already said he bought an Annex A version of his modem.

Comment: Some vendors declare their device as suitable for Annex A just because they have the Annex A firmware in it, despite the fact that the hardware could also handle B/J.

Comment: Yes, but it's not clear one way or the other from his router spec http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/cat-15_Archer-D7.html#specifications. It just says ITU-T G.992.1 but not whether it's Annex A or B or both.

Comment: Yes. -- So I think I missed your point, sorry. Do you feel my comment isn't helpful?

Comment: Not at all, your comments are very helpful ;)

Comment: That's very kind. I'm still striving for a more continuous positive attitude like yours. My commet was meant as an axtension to your answer. Having freelanced for a vendor once, I thought I'd throw in some less theoretical aspects.